# New column based on conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
my_data = data.frame(ITEM_GROUP = c("1","2","3","1","4"),
                     ITEM_NAME = c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Mango","Papaya"), 
                     ITEM = c("Apple","Bana","Orange","sweet","Paneer"))
```

I have a list initially it

```
my_data$name <- apply(my_data, 
                      1, 
                      function(x) as.integer(any(grep("Apple|Orange|Milk|Paneer",x))))

ITEM_GROUP ITEM_NAME   ITEM name
1              Apple  Apple    1
2             Banana   Bana    0
3             Orange Orange    1
1              Mango  sweet    0
4             Papaya Paneer    1
```

[image]

Instead of 0 and 1 I am trying the following output

```
ITEM_GROUP   ITEM_NAME   ITEM        name

1              Apple     Apple        Apple
2             Banana     Bana         Unknown
3              Orange    Orange       Orange
1             Mango      Sweet        Sweet
4             Papaya     Paneer       Paneer
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is your 2nd row "Unknown" and your 4th row "Sweet"?

Answer (score 1):

We could do a `rowwise`, get the `intersect` between the columns 'ITEM_NAME', 'ITEM', and the vector of values.  If none of them matches, return 'Unknown'

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(name = c(intersect(c(ITEM_NAME, ITEM), 
        c("Apple", "Orange", "Milk", "Paneer")), "Unknown")[1]) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  ITEM_GROUP ITEM_NAME ITEM   name   
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  
1 1          Apple     Apple  Apple  
2 2          Banana    Bana   Unknown
3 3          Orange    Orange Orange 
4 1          Mango     sweet  Unknown
5 4          Papaya    Paneer Paneer
```

Comment: can we add ignore.case = TRUE , to this my_data$name <- apply( my_data, 1, function(x)as.integer(any(grep("Apple|Orange|Milk|Paneer",x))))@akrun

Comment: @Perry do you have different case

Comment: It is the same case but they are  ignore.case = TRUE

Comment: @Perry your function yes, it can have `ignore.case = TRUE` and specify `value = TRUE` instead of `as.integer`

Comment: @Perry you need `apply(my_data[2:3], 1, function(x) c(grep("Apple|Orange|Milk|Paneer",x, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE), "Unknown")[1])#
[1] "Apple"   "Unknown" "Orange"  "Unknown" "Paneer"`